# Handle (TaskId) Redirect in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

User's controllers needs to concatenate the task ID to be obtained in a .js that is loaded by the Architecture (me) when the view is loaded. This mechanism is necessary to tasks control. In this context:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String create(@Valid Vote vote, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                uiModel.addAttribute("vote", vote);
                addDateTimeFormatPatterns(uiModel);
                return "votes/create";
            }
            uiModel.asMap().clear();
            vote.persist();
            return "redirect:/votes/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(vote.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest) + 
"**?ArcSpring.idTask=" + httpServletRequest.getParameter("ArcSpring.idTask")**;
            }
```

Is there a way to handle this redirect in the way I can concatenate the task ID to make it transparent for users?

I tried with a customized class extending from UrlBasedViewResolver, capturing the url and adding the attributes by my own, but with no kind of success.

Comment: What do you mean by "transparent for users"?

Comment: That user's wouldn't need to code that. That would be automatic for them. The aim is that: return "redirect:/votes/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(vote.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest) + 
"**?ArcSpring.idTask=" + httpServletRequest.getParameter("ArcSpring.idTask")**; would be only  return "redirect:/votes/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(vote.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);